# Google Apps Script Dashboard filtercolumnindex

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, dashboard

I am trying to get my string filter to search multiple columns for a given value. I tried doing this :

```
var qualFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(59)
.setFilterColumnIndex(61).setFilterColumnIndex(62).setFilterColumnIndex(63)
.setFilterColumnIndex(64).setFilterColumnIndex(65).setFilterColumnIndex(66)
.setFilterColumnIndex(67).setFilterColumnIndex(68).setFilterColumnIndex(69)
.setFilterColumnIndex(70).setFilterColumnIndex(71).setFilterColumnIndex(72)
.setFilterColumnIndex(73).setFilterColumnIndex(74).setFilterColumnIndex(75)
.setFilterColumnIndex(76).setFilterColumnIndex(77).setFilterColumnIndex(78)
.setFilterColumnIndex(79).setFilterColumnIndex(80).setFilterColumnIndex(81)
.setFilterColumnIndex(82).setFilterColumnIndex(83).setFilterColumnIndex(84)
.build();
```

however this makes it so that all columns much match the value I searched. I would like to make it so that only one column has to contain the value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at this and there does not seem to be an easy / simple answer (or any really answer at all). 
I'm sure you have had a look through [Google Documentation for filters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#stringfilter) and it only takes one argument. I have tried to enter multiple but it just comes up with errors.

I can give you an answer as to why your code is not filtering on all the columns that you have listed. 
Google are using the dot notation in their api (you can find out more here: [Mozilla - Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).). 
This is the equvillent of saying

```
var filterColumn = 1;
filterColumn = 2;
filterColumn = 3; 
""
```

So each time it is overwriting the previous column to search on.

It's a really tough one but I think you may have to write a custom script / interface (I haven't yet tried it) and even still it might not work.

Hope this helps shed some light on the problem. :)